# Connect to Wifi SSID and get SSID information

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I have a react native app for iOS.  I am using the the simulator via xCode for development.
I am trying to use the below library to get the SSID or even connect to an SSID but keep getting an internal error.

Package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-wifi-reborn

I have `Access WIFI Information` enabled on xCode. I was getting an issue previously and by adding this it resolved it but now I get a response just as `internal error`.

**Example**

```
WifiManager.getCurrentWifiSSID().then(
ssid => {
console.log("Your current connected wifi SSID is " + ssid);
},
(err) => {
console.log("Cannot get current SSID! " + err);
}
);
```

**Response**

```
Cannot get current SSID! internal error
```

Note that on the simulator I do not see any Wifi Settings at all.  Is this the issue? Must I use a physical device for this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the link (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-wifi-reborn) that you have provided:

> iOS
> You need use enable Access WIFI Information, with correct profile. Hotspot  Configuration is required in order to connect to networks.

`com.apple.developer.networking.wifi-info` and `com.apple.developer.networking.HotspotConfiguration` (if you need this) should be added to capabilities of your iOS app.

> iOS 13
> You need put "Privacy - Location When In Use Usage Description" or "Privacy - Location Always and When In Use Usage Description" in Settings -> info

You should add these keys with description into `Info.plist` of your iOS app project.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried add the Hotspot Configuration Entitlement also?

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/entitlements/com_apple_developer_networking_hotspotconfiguration?language=objc

I should not be needed just to get the SSID, but I believe react-native-wifi-reborn requires it. I got internal errors when trying to connect to a protected SSID without it.